# Flutter TextAlign ignored in Row widget

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment

I'm using `TextAlign` to centre one piece of text and then again to send another piece of text to the right, all contained in a `Row`, but the alignment does nothing at all.

```
Scaffold(
  body: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text('Align Centre', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
      Text('Align Right', textAlign: TextAlign.right),
    ],
  ),
);
```

You can see here it's ignored completely:

[image]

Comment: You should try wrapping your Text in a Container with fixed size, or Flex, or Expanded to see how the Alignment works

Comment: @Franken Frank Ok I tried that but it doesn't improve anything. The Row already takes up the full width of the screen anyway so I don't see why the TextAlign doesn't align itself accordingly. Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I think you misunderstood TextAlignment. It's for aligning the Text inside its Container, so if you want to align your children of a row or column, you use its mainAxisAlignment field. However, if you want to customize the position each of your widget in a row, afaik you have to use SizedBox.

Comment: @Franken Frank So can you align anything inside a Row? I don't see how sizedBox can be used to achieve this either. Row and Column are the most common widgets, simply aligning things inside them would seem to be one of the most basic requirements?

Comment: Well there's MainAxisAlignment but you want to put your Text in arbitrary positions no?

Comment: @Franken Frank Centreing one to the right with one in the centre is about as normal as you can get.

Comment: Well there's no default alignment setting for that but you can achieve by setting the MainAxisAlignment to stretch and put an invisible widget (SizedBox, Expanded, Flex ..) as the first child of the row

Comment: @Franken Frank That wouldn't work on all screen sizes if you're just pushing the widgets around with sizedboxes. This seems to be a major hole in the Flutter framework. Something absolutely basic like this is missing.

Comment: Then use Flex or Expanded, they take up spaces in the Row proportionally

Comment: @Franken Frank The answers below already talked about using Expanded but it doesn't work. You can get the text over to the right but the other piece of text can't be centred. Plus the centred piece of text may be wrapped in a row itself or the one on the right in a column for example, and the pieces of text may be of different lengths so they can't be guaranteed to be all of equal size.

Comment: Have you tried setting the main axis alignment to spaceEvenly or spaceAround because by default it's start

Comment: `MainAxisAlignment.text` ? I doubt main axis alignment would work since it just seems align everything as a whole. What should really happen is the text items should align themselves with the width of the row. Or if there are multiple pieces of text in a column for the centre part, that should also be able to align itself within the outer row too.

Comment: typo, edited my comment

Comment: @Franken Frank Yeah `MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly` doesn't change anything at all in fact....with or without Expanded widgets around each text widget. Nothing seems to work apart from dodgy workarounds that have to be adjusted depending on the conditions.

Comment: is this what you expect it to be? https://imgur.com/a/KFYoEbf

Comment: @Franken Frank Yes it should centre itself with the width of the row it is contained in. That actual method though instantly breaks if you put for example the centre text inside a row widget. Then it is no longer being centred within the width of the row it is contained in.

Comment: works perfectly fine for me: https://imgur.com/a/36eBWdG. You clearly misunderstood how alignments settings for each widget work

Comment: @Franken Frank Do you have two pieces of short text in the centre row? It looks like it still says 'Align centre'. I can't see the whole code. Try changing it to 'at' and 'in'.

Comment: @Franken Frank It does work anyway. You should post that as an answer. It's a strange solution and adds a lot more code to do something incredibly simple but it works. We've already had four answers with two deleted because they didn't work. I'm used to React Native with CSS where everything is simple and logical.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are after something like this:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.3333333,),
            Expanded(child: Text('Align Centre adding more text heree....', textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
            Expanded(child: Text('Align Right', textAlign: TextAlign.right)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

By adding an empty container first into the row it pushed the Align Center text into the middle.

Edit: Instead of using an expanded widget used a sized box instead and fix the width to consume a 3rd of the view.

Comment: That's really weird. Is that in the Flutter documents? That doesn't seem to be logical. Is it a bug or something?

Comment: No you are simply splitting the row into 3 equal width sections left, center and right.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work. Try with a two pieces of text in a Row for the centre text and they're not in the centre anymore. Try a Row in the Expanded widget and two pieces of short text like 'Re' and 'st'. The container is just pushing it a bit, it's not really centreing it properly.

Comment: @Hasen Due to it being a expanded widget, when more text is added the width of the first container is reduced to make space for the more text, so to counter this i changed the first container to a sizedbox and set the width to a 3rd of the view.

Comment: Yeah I don't think using Expanded is the way to go. To be honest I don't see any reason my original code doesn't work...doesn't make any sense at all. It should just align the text within the width of the row it's contained in...

Comment: Its hard to explain but your original code is working as I would expect. The width of a text element is only as big as it content so when you apply text align center visually you don't see anything because its center within that width. So when you add them all to a row they will stack like that but they are all correctly aligned within their text widgets just not within the row.

Comment: It should be centred within the width of the row because that is what it is in. Look at the screenshot to see the row width. There's zero use to centre it within the width that is remaining after deducting the width of the element on the right? I can't see when you'd ever need that behaviour..

Comment: Your solution is clearly a workaround and in any case, it doesn't work. Try putting the middle text inside of a row with two pieces of short text. Suddenly it's no longer in the centre.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap Text with Expanded widget:

```
    Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: Text('Align Centre', textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
          Expanded(child: Text('Align Right', textAlign: TextAlign.right)),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

By default Text takes up space only required for content.

Or what you probably want:

```
    Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned.fill(
              child: Text('Align Centre', textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
          Positioned.fill(
              child: Text('Align Right', textAlign: TextAlign.right)),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. The text is off to the right but the centred text is still on the left..

Comment: Use Stack instead of Row

Comment: It doesn't work with Stack either. Try wrapping the centre text in a Row widget and it moves off to the left...it's a very limited solution.

Comment: You misunderstand purpose of Row widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html

Comment: textAlign property belongs to Text widget, but not to Row.

Comment: Like I said, they use TextAlign in the example here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html I suggest you read about it, it's the first example at the top of the page. I think you didn't look at your own link..

Comment: They use Text widget with textAlign property.

Comment: Ok I see what you're referring to now. I think you misunderstood, what I'm saying is there still needs to be a way to align a row in the centre of a row. My point was that using TextAlign with text widgets inside a row is fine according to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scaffold(
    body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                width:screen_width/2,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text('Align Centre',),
            ),
            Container(
                width:screen_width/2,
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: Text('Align right',),
            ),
        ],
    ),
);
```

and you can get screen_widht by

> double screen_width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;